# Resetting FakeApplication in-memory-database H2 before/after each test

Tags: scala, playframework, h2, specs2

How do I reset the database inside the FakeApplication using inMemoryDatabase after or before each test? I want the state of the database returned to its initial state after each single test. Either rollback or clearing the database and running SetupData() again is fine.

I have tried many various things. The database is never reset between each test. How do I do this?
When running the following test suite the state of the database continues from test to test. So if I modify some data in Test2 then it is affecting Test3.

```
trait TestUtil {
  /**
   * Executes a block of code in a running application.
   */
  def running[T](fakeApp: FakeApplication)(block: => T): T = {
    synchronized {
      try {
        Play.start(fakeApp)
        setup_data()
        block
      } finally {
        Play.stop()
      }
    }
  }

  def setup_data() = {
    //add data to the database
  }
}
```

I tried using the above trait to have the Play App stop after each test but it does not help.

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ConditionTests2 extends Specification with TestUtil {
  sequential  // Make the tests run sequentially instead of in parallel

  // test1
  "element with id 1" should {
    "should have name PETER" in {
      running(new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))) {
        // name should be "PETER"
      }
    }
  }

  // test2
  "renaming element with id 1" should {
    "successfully modify element 1" in {
      running(new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))) {
        // Set Name = "John"
      }
    }
  }

  // test3
  "element with id 1" should {
    "should have name PETER" in {
      running(new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))) {
        // name should be "PETER"
        // fails because name is now JOHN
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`OneAppPerTest`](http://doc.scalatest.org/plus-play/1.0.0/index.html#org.scalatestplus.play.OneAppPerTest) from [scalatestplus-play](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-play)? That way a new FakeApp will be used for each test.